# How to pass arguments in __VA_ARGS to a 2d character array?

Tags: c, macros

I need to get result from __VA_ARGS to a function, and from there I need to pass string of each argument to a 2d character array.

Comment: Give us your code. If you don't have code, try something yourself first and read the forum rules.

Comment: You have been a member here for a long time, you should have had plenty of time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), as well as [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

If you are under C99, you can use [compound literals](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO(...) func( \
    sizeof((char *[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(char *), \
    (char *[]){__VA_ARGS__} \
)

void func(size_t n, char **p)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", p[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    MACRO("abc", "def", "ghi");
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that `__VA_ARGS__` are evaluated twice in order to get the number of elements using `sizeof`, as an alternative you can send `NULL` as last parameter (sentinel):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define macro(...) func((char *[]){__VA_ARGS__, NULL})

void func(char **p)
{
    while (*p != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", *p);
        p++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    macro("abc", "def", "ghi");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/n4Tzbo37q